# What antivirus software is recommended for Windows Server and Small Business Server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, anti-virus, windows-sbs-2008, windows-sbs

I wounder what antivirus software is recommended for a Windows Server 2008 or a Small Business Server 2008.

I would like to have one that:

- Is easy to maintain.
- Has good performance

I don't need anyone that is complex and has support for clients. It's a small office with just a few computers.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/7/what-is-the-best-enterprise-virus-scanning-system

Comment: Well in this case he asks about server antivirus software, not corporate ones :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that Forefront client security (server equivalent of MS security essentials) should be the easiest thing to implement on server OS

http://www.microsoft.com/forefront/clientsecurity/en/us/default.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I have to say that forefront works great, has caught stuff that symntec didn't and isn't a resource pig.  Pricing is also better (although in this case you'd have to check) as you pay per user not per system.